# FullCalendar synchronization

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I need to synchronize **FullCalendar** - when an event object is dropped on a calendar it has to be shown on every other calendar opened. Right now I'm using `refetchEvents`, which is triggered by `websockets`, but it is very slow and resource consuming.

Is there a way to programmatically draw an event on a FullCalendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call `.fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventObject, true);` on the other calendars, this won't do any additional server calls. [docs here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)

Answer (score 0):

`.fullCalendar('renderEVent',event,true)` or call

`.fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);` inside eventReceive when you initialize the calendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        ...

        eventReceive : function(event) {
              ...
              $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);
         },

         ...
});
```

should do the trick

***edit:*** realized this was an old thread, apologies